# Displaying XML data on a webpage without using files

Tags: java, php, xml

At the moment I have a lot of client connections sending data to a server which then aggregates that data into an XML file. The clients can then view a webpage that updates the content pane every 1 second via AJAX with the latest contents of the file.

My question is simply does anyone have any suggestions on how I might skip writing the file all together and somehow send the XML data straight to the webpage? Right now I am writing the file every 2 seconds, but would like to do this at an increased frequency, maybe ever 0.75 seconds, at which rate writing to the file could become an expensive operation as well as the general health of the hard drive.

The web portion uses php (on Apache 2.2), so I was thinking of perhaps having the page create a socket connection to the server, and the server can write to that socket and the page can update as data is pushed down, but I am wondering if there are any better ways to accomplish this type of task.

The XML files are generally not that large, less than 10KB so if my concerns are unfounded than I would like to hear that as well.

Comment: When you recieve the data, you don't write them imediately but periodically write them every 2 second? Why?

Comment: Assuming I have 20 clients, each client sends updates every 0.5 seconds, so if I wrote everytime I received data on a per-client basis, that could result in a write every 0.1 seconds or less. At the moment, the most recent client update is held in the client's object and when the xml writer is triggered, it pulls this data from each client object and writes it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like PHP's `DomDocument` to build the file in memory and then echo it out using `DOMDocument::saveXML` - see http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

Instead of then using AJaX to call the file `/something/something/darkside/something.xml` you'd instead call `/something/something/darkside/something.xml.php` (for example) - and that PHP file would just be dropping out XML.

To ensure that it IS interpreted as XML it's best to include a header like:

```
header('Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8');
```

**BUT ...**
I think your issue there is with saving that data? As I understand it, and I might be wrong here, you've got lots of clients creating a single, saved resource (in the form of an XML file) which is updated by actions performed by *all* clients?

This means you've got to save something somewhere on the server. Which means you've realistically got 2 options, save the data in a file (as you're doing) or in a database (though technically even the database writes a to the filesystem somewhere).

Personally I'd use a database - they're designed for grunt-work and `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`) the data in XML format using `DomDocument::saveXML` ... you'd end up with something (conceptually) like:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO table({fields}) VALUES({values including $xmlDomDoc->saveXML())}");
```

Then read that back when you need it ... probably pretty much the same principle that you're using but doing it in a database rather than file-based system.

Comment: Correct, the XML file is the single saved resource containing information on all clients. The file is updated periodically (at the moment it is written every 2 seconds) with information supplied by all clients.

I will look into the efficiency of using a database over text files.

Comment: I think this is a good approach (although, it does add complexity because now a database is involved).  When the client sends updates to the server, the server would instead save the data to a database.  Then, when a client requests the XML document, the server would dynamically build an XML document from scratch using data from the database.  Also, storing the data in a database gives you more power in terms of manipulating the data.  For example, what if you decided you wanted the data in the XML document to be sorted by a date field?  This would be easy to accomplish with a database.